# Multiple instances of Swiftmailer in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

**Symfony2** uses a [**Swiftmailer**](http://swiftmailer.org/) bundle to send emails.

To use and configure Swiftmailer in Symfony2, one has to use such a configuration as [explained](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/email/email.html#configuration) in the docs, e.g. by using YAML:

```
swiftmailer:
    transport:  smtp
    encryption: ssl
    auth_mode:  login
    host:       smtp.gmail.com
    username:   your_username
    password:   your_password
```

The Swiftmailer is defined in Symfony2 as a service and an instance of it can be obtained in a controller as follows:

```
$mailerinstance = $this->get('mailer');
```

Now, let's suppose that two different configurations are required for the Swiftmailer, e.g. one that uses email spooling (e.g. for a scheduled newsletter) and another that sends immediately all the new emails (e.g. for the password lost service). Thus, I guess that two separated instances of the Swiftmailer should be defined. **How can I do that in Symfony2?**

Comment: Now you can do this with swiftmailer v2.3.3+:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474822/swiftmailer-configuration-for-more-than-one-accounts-in-symfony-2?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no default symfony way to have 2 different instances. But you can just make a new class that extends swiftmailer, make it to be a service and just pass to the parent constructor your different configuration.

Comment: Really?!?! Omg, this is insane! By the way... I'll follow your suggestions!

Comment: There should be something like for the entity managers! One can defined multiple entity managers... it would be nice to define multiple Swiftmailer instances!

Answer (score 4):

```
swiftmailer:
    default_mailer: second_mailer
    mailers:
        first_mailer:
        # ...
        second_mailer:
        # ...

// ...

// returns the first mailer
$container->get('swiftmailer.mailer.first_mailer');

// also returns the second mailer since it is the default mailer
$container->get('swiftmailer.mailer');

// returns the second mailer
$container->get('swiftmailer.mailer.second_mailer');
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html#using-multiple-mailers

Comment: I think you're missing a tab from the second config line.

Comment: 2.1 is very old. You need considering an update perhaps.

Comment: I found a way by creating different environments. Since I would call the second account for a Command, that works fine as long as I add --env=OTHER_ENV after the call.