# Setting default_mailer for Swiftmailer in Symfony2 not working

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer, spooler

I'm using Symfony 2.7 which comes with SwiftmailerBundle 2.3.8.

This is my configuration

```
swiftmailer:
    mailers:
        spool_mailer:
            transport: "%mailer_transport%"
            host:      "%mailer_host%"
            username:  "%mailer_user%"
            password:  "%mailer_password%"
            spool:
                type: file
                path: %kernel.root_dir%/spool

        instant_mailer:
            transport: "%mailer_transport%"
            host:      "%mailer_host%"
            username:  "%mailer_user%"
            password:  "%mailer_password%"
    default_mailer: spool_mailer
```

I want to use 2 mailers, one for spooling and one for sending them instantly.

These two commands will work just fine, the email is either spooled or sent instantly.

```
 $this->get('swiftmailer.mailer.instant_mailer')->send($email);
 $this->get('swiftmailer.mailer.spool_mailer')->send($email);
```

However,

```
  $this->get('mailer')->send($email);
```

Doesn't fetch the `default_mailer` which is the spooler in my case, but it sends it instantly. I've seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18422803/2077972) that this is possible, but maybe that answer is incorrect.

Did I miss something in the configuration file? Or am I not calling it right?

Comment: I **really donno** why but I have seen that declaring the `default_mailer: spool_mailer` line above defining the mailers will do it. I don't have any supporting docs for this too. But it is worthy trying I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem, even though using symfony version 2.6.8.
The only solution I found at this moment is: remove the default_mailer parameter, and set the default mailer with such name, this is: **default**.
So your configuration would be like:

```
swiftmailer:
    mailers:
        default: # your named spool_mailer
            transport: "%mailer_transport%"
            host:      "%mailer_host%"
            username:  "%mailer_user%"
            password:  "%mailer_password%"
            spool:
                type: file
                path: %kernel.root_dir%/spool

        instant_mailer:
            transport: "%mailer_transport%"
            host:      "%mailer_host%"
            username:  "%mailer_user%"
            password:  "%mailer_password%"
```

From now the object gotten from $this->getContainer()->get('swiftmailer.mailer'); will be the one defined as **default** and NO more errors like this will be shown:

```
[Swift_TransportException]                                                         
  Connection could not be established with host localhost [Connection refused #111]
```

This configuration worked for me in the project I am currently working on.

I hope it helps.